# How to get $\cosh^{-1}(\coth (\ln 3))$?

Tags: trigonometry

Tried plug into the definition formula, however got two solutions
$$\ln 2  \text{  and } -\ln 2$$
The solution gave only one answer $\ln 2 $, why the other is wrong?

Comment: Depends on the branches we are considering.  Usually, $\cosh^{-1}(x)>0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I plotted the graph of $cosh^{-1}$ in Wolfram alpha, it truns out to be a bell shaped curve, why there are two branches?

Comment: How would you graph $y=\sqrt{x}$?  How is this different from the inverse of $f(x)=x^2$?